# How can I get all passes name for O2 level optimization in llvm / clang

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, llvm

How can I get all passes name for O1 ,O2 , O3  level optimization in llvm / clang . I am working with performance analysis with LLVM . So I am trying to find what are the passes are enable for O2 level optimization or O3 level optimization

I tried with few linux command
opt -O2 -debug-pass=Arguments -disable-output
clang -O2 -help

Nothing worked out .

Answer (score 0):

clang -O2 -mllvm -debug-pass=Arguments file.c